# Exact dimensions of studless Technic beams

Tags: technic

I'm looking for the exact dimensions of the studless Technic beams. I found a number of answers for studded beams but there are some more aspects for the studless beams which are not covered.

I'm especially interested in these parts:

- [Technic, Liftarm 5 x 7 Open Center Thick](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=64179)
- [Technic, Liftarm 1 x 9 Thick](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=40490) (or any other length)

Comment: What level of precision do you need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Liftarms are 1 stud wide (8 mm) and 7 mm high so they have a 7:8 aspect ratio. (width is the direction parallel to they axis of rotation of the peg holes).

As pictured in the link, the 1x9 liftarm has the hole orientated vertically. So the height is 8mm. The width is 7mm and the length is 9 x 8 mm = 72mm.

Similarly, the 5x7 open center thick has 
height=8mm
width=5 x 8mm=40mm
length = 7 x 8mm= 56mm
opening width=3x8mm=24mm
opening length= 5x8mm=40mm

Comment: That sounds reasonable. I'm just curios: Where did you find this?

Comment: Sorry, should have included a reference:
Chapter 1 of
THE UNOFFICIAL LEGO® TECHNIC BUILDER’S GUIDE
Paweł “Sariel” Kmiec

This is a great technic reference and doubles as a primer on mechanical engineering. Available as a free ebook in pdf form.

Comment: PS For fun, you can also look at CAD representations of the pieces. For example, Google Sketchup, free version. You can download technic pieces into it from the marketplace and measure in the app. Assuming you trust these to be authentic and faithful renderings. You get the same dimensions I quoted above. The stud proportions are actually quite important to keep in mind when designing models.

Answer (score 6):

**Technic, Liftarm 5 x 7 Open Center Thick**

- Height = 7.86mm
- Width = 39.80mm
- Length = 55.85mm
- Opening width = 24.08mm
- Opening length = 40.20mm

**Technic, Liftarm 1 x 9 Thick** (oriented as shown on Bricklink image):

- Height = 7.86mm
- Width = 7.44mm
- Length = 71.36mm

(measured with digital caliper, precision +/-0.05mm)

Comment: Thanks for doing the measuring! Since I don't have an approriate tool, that's already helpfull. Actually I was hoping someone does now the exact values as they are weill known (and alredas answered in this forum).

Comment: Thx for the dimensions, Philo did you measure other parts?

Comment: To increase precision, you can stack multiple beams