# What are the size of Lego Technic Parts?

Tags: technic, customization, size

I'm creating a LEGO Mindstorms catalogue for a school project. I measured the LEGO parts and I made an average size. My goal is to create new parts with a Rapid prototyping machine and I wanted to make sure that I used the good dimension.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exact dimensions of studless Technic beams](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1762/exact-dimensions-of-studless-technic-beams)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know where you got that image, but you could always try and print the brick using the dimensions shown.

Using the brick ([#32316](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=32316)) shown in your example it might be possible to produce a 3D model using the 32316.dat file that's available in the [LDraw](http://www.ldraw.org/) library. The next problem would be placing the brick in a model and exporting it as a file type that is actually compatible with CAD software.

I'm not sure how accurate the bricks in the LDraw library are as they're primarily for illustration purposes as digital models.

Comment: There's some notes on using the LDraw parts for 3D Printing on [Is it possible to build LEGO bricks with a makerbot 3D replicator print](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/q/1241/56)

Comment: Thx Ambo100, i made this image usign CATIA. i didn't wanted to spend too much money on trying different configuration. :)